# how to convert string data into json?

Tags: java, json, shell

here string data values comes from shell script code.i need to show this resultant values in json format

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
             Process pr = rt.exec(new String[]{"/home/admin/institutestatus.sh"});

         BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
             String line = "";

             while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {

                 Gson gson =new Gson();
                 System.out.println(gson.toJson(line));
             }
         } catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println(e.toString());
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

Comment: what doesn't work for you

Comment: i need json format output

Comment: There's no point for converting `String` to json `String` by this method: what do you really want to get on what input from this script?

Comment: If you want to convert a string to json it does not matter where the string comes from. What matters is what result you get versus what you expected.

Comment: i need string variable in json format

Comment: [gson.toJson(Object)](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson(java.lang.Object)) just serialize this Object, so you'll get only json representation of some single `String`s

Comment: This is my output
"nename is VIT"
"necollegecode is 1"  
 
but i am expecting json format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();

 while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("value",line);
    arr.add(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used this function to convert `InputStream` to `String` and the to `JSONObject`.

```
public static String load(final InputStream in) {
    String data = "";
    try {
        InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(in, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
        String read = br.readLine();
        while (read != null) {
            sb.append(read);
            read = br.readLine();
        }
        data = sb.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the GSON in order to don't have to work with the Strings in the first place...